# Simple, how do I use variables in Google Docs Script, mailapp.sendmail(message), Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sendmail, google-docs

I want to use variables in the example from Google but the standard substitution is not working. What is the trick?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)

(I am having trouble with the Stackoverflow.com Code block setting so advice there would help too: manually input 4 spaces on every line? really?)

[below: missing code above because pain in the butt to add 4 spaces for every line]

```
to_01 = "email@example.com"
subject_01 = s.getRange('B2').getValues();

 MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: to_01, //<<<<<<<does not work
 subject: subject_01, //<<<<<<does not work
 htmlBody: "wind today Logo <br> <img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>" +
           "and later YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>",
 inlineImages:
   {
     googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
     youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob
   }
});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"does not work"_? The syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: "to_01" and "subject_01" above produce weird results in the email. e.g. when I use "subject_01" the email arrives with this in the subject field: "[Ljava.lang.Object;@3fda2ff9" (without quotes)

Comment: `"[Ljava.lang.Object;@3fda2ff9"` is probably what `subject_01.toString()` is

Comment: This is in "B2" of the sheet:
 ="Next in the Gorge -- "&E2

Comment: Sure but that doesn't mean `toString()` on `s.getRange('B2').getValues();` will return that value. What _does_ `s.getRange('B2').getValues();` return?

Comment: It was returning:
"Next in the Gorge -- 4/18/2013 20:44:48" in other trials, i.e. when using simple "sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)" format it works to substitute "subject_01" for "subject".  Specifically, this was working but I want more control over the content: 
    MailApp.sendEmail(to_01, subject_01, body_01, {attachments:  
    [attachment01, attachment02]});"

Comment: OK, I changed to `subject_01 = "Wind today"` and that works. So why is it not getting the string from the spreadsheet? BTW `var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('email');`

Comment: So, the `subject` field is the only one acting weird. When I use `to_01` for the recipient it works; I can also add `body_01 = s.getRange('C2').getValues();` to the `body` in my original question and it works. Subject is not working with any Spreadsheet generated string.

Comment: Fixed it by copy and pasting from the working strings, e.g. `to_01`, then changed cell. There must have been a hidden something or other in the original `subject_01`. Thanks, sorry it was something in my code, or maybe the Google code I copied.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no actual problem to be solved. 